# Confusion regarding the *? regular expression operator

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, microsoft-expression-web

So I want to search a string, using the below regular expression:

```
border-.*\.5pt
```

to find all `border-top`, `border-bottom`, etc CSS properties in a file with a border thickness of `.5pt`. It generally works great, but it's too greedy.

For example all of the below comes back as a single match:

```
border-top:solid #1F497D .5pt;border-bottom:solid #1F497D .5pt
```

I want those two CSS properties to be two separate matches.

So I tried to modify my regular expression to:

```
border-.*?\.5pt
```

Using `?` to make it non-greedy. However, after that modification, nothing matches.

Can anyone explain why I see this behavior? What am I missing?

(If it's worth knowing, I'm using Microsoft Expression Web's 'find with regular expressions' when doing this search.)

Comment: [I can only tell that it works here](http://regex101.com/r/wV7lF6), so maybe it's your app's regex engine...

Comment: @Wrikken, you're right. I incorrectly assumed that there would be consistency in regex syntax across Microsoft products. It turns out that PowerShell (the reference I was using) has different operators than Expression Web. Lesson learned. Thanks for taking a look at it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no one "regular expression" language. While there are broad commonalities, details differ from implementation to implementation. Many regexes use `-` to be the non-greedy *"0 or more"*, others use `*?`. Apparently [Microsoft Expression Web uses `@`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295435.aspx).

In short, regexes can differ, so you'll often need to RTM for the one you're using to find its range of capabilities and detailed syntax (i.e. support for alteration/backtracking/etc., grouping character, set shorthand, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it. I didn't realize that even across Microsoft products regex syntax changes. I was using a PowerShell regex reference assuming that it would apply to Expression Web. Thank you for the response. Good to know for the future.

Answer (score 3):

`.*?` is the badest, so to say "antipattern" for Regular Expressions. It is commonly used as a "Match-something-until-the-string-i-want" Pattern - but it isn't.

Especially when combining multiple `.*?` within ONE pattern, it may lead to very wrong and unexpected results.

For your Case - as stated in the comments - It works. (Maybe you did something wrong?)

However, it is ALWAYS a good idea to be more specific, when generating a regex pattern.
ALWAYS KEEP IN MIND that `.*?` can be ANYTHING. Also Stuff you really don't want to match!

In your example, i would use something like this: `border-(?:[^:]+):\s*(?:[^\s]+)\s+(?:\#[a-fA-F0-9]{6})\s+(?:\d*(?:\.\d+)?)pt;?`

It is more specific, but matches the given Requirements, ignores all whitespaces that dont make sence, and even matches border widths, regardles if they are written as `.2`, `3` or `4.1`. If you remove the `?:` from the single match Groups you can also match every single attribute, if required. : Position, Border type, Color and thickness.

The pattern `border-([^:]+):\s*([^\s]+)\s+(\#[a-fA-F0-9]{6})\s+(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)pt;?` with your string `border-top:solid #1F497D .5pt;border-bottom:solid #1F497D .5pt` will match:

First Match:

```
1.top
2.solid
3.#1F497D
4..5
```

Second Match:

```
1.bottom
2.solid
3.#1F497D
4..5
```